# What is the use of status of MPI_Isend obtained using MPI_Wait?

Tags: c, mpi, intel-mpi

***Case: 1.*** What is the use of status obtained using MPI_Wait()

```
if(rank==0)
MPI_Isend(&buffer0, count, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request0);
if(rank==1)
MPI_Recv(&buffer1, count, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if(rank==0)
MPI_Wait(&request0, &status);
// Can i use status here to do something?
MPI_Finalize();
```

***Case:2.*** Use of status is clear here (Just added for comparison)

```
if(rank==0)
MPI_Ssend(&buffer0, count, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
if(rank==1)
MPI_Irecv(&buffer1, count, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request1);

if(rank==1)
MPI_Wait(&request1, &status);
printf("The source is %d", status.MPI_SOURCE);
MPI_Finalize();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally `MPI_Status` is used to get the the following properties for received messages.

1. rank of the sender, (`status.MPI_SOURCE`) particularly relevant when `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` was used.
2. tag of the message, (`status.MPI_TAG`) particularly relevant when `MPI_ANY_TAG` was used
3. element-count that was *sent*, which may differ from posted receive buffer, using `MPI_Get_count`.

For send messages, you can use the status to test for `MPI_Test_cancelled`. Further, for functions that return multiple status, such as `MPI_Waitall`, in the case of errors, you can use `status[i].MPI_ERROR`. The main wait function will return `MPI_ERR_IN_STATUS` in this case.

If you do not need any of those, you may pass `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE` instead of a `MPI_Status*`.

Comment: Can you please check Case:1 once more? I'm talking about the status in MPI_Wait(&request0, &status); This MPI_Wait was used to check out MPI_Isend.